# allocate dynamic multiple array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc, dynamic-arrays

Let's say we have the following design:

```
typedef struct {
  double **pdouble;
  int *pint
}foo;
```

now I want to allocate:

```
foo *pfoo;
```

the thing is that the total number of pdouble is known, lets say its n; if we say **pdouble is like pdouble [a][b], a is also known. means a*b =n. but b is dynamic. mean pdouble[1] might contain b column and pdouble[2] might have b' number of column, also b and b',b" ... will generate in the program gradually.
its worth noting that b+b'+b"+ ... = n.
is it possible to allocate foo using just knowing n and a?

I'm going to edit it a little so my question will become more understandable.

```
allocation_func(in size, int block_size)
foo *pfoo;

pfoo = (foo*) malloc(sizeof(foo))

/*some code here to do block_size number of *double which I don't know*/


foo->pdouble = (double**) malloc ( size * sizeof(double))

}
```

I ignored errors and other required thing which everybody knows.
Thats all;

Comment: "if we say **pdouble is like pdouble [a][b]", that just means that we have no understanding at all about what pointers are and what arrays are.

Comment: You can allocate `foo` without knowing *anything* about a's, n's, b's, or the like. its a *struct*. `foo` appears to have nothing to do with what your *real* issue seems to be, namely understanding the differences between pointers and arrays, and managing a dynamic pointer array.

Comment: confusing question. Just simple allocation answered.

Comment: thanks for not understanding the question and simply arguing about why someone should have such a silly question.

Comment: Also what is significance of casting to `(foo*)` in this `c` code `pfoo =(foo*) malloc(sizeof(foo))`?

Comment: I'm trying to show steps that I'm going in my code. not very important. some people questioned about understanding pointer, I just written that part to show off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First allocate `struct` memory

```
 foo *pfoo = malloc(sizeof *pfoo);
```

then allocate memory for `struct` member `double **pdouble;`

```
//for example purpose i take 50x50 array

pfoo->pdouble = malloc(50* sizeof(double *));

for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
    pfoo->pdouble [i] = malloc(50* sizeof(double ));
```

And finally allocate memory for `struct` member `int *pint`

```
 pfoo->pint=malloc(100*sizeof(int)); //100 is just for example
```

Comment: Lose the leading asterisk in all put the first snippet. All those `*pfoo->` should be `pfoo->`. And your last allocation should probably involve the size of an `int` at some point.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks..it's copy paste error from first snippet.

Comment: @jayesh: `pint=malloc(100)` should be `pint=malloc(100*sizeof(int))`

Comment: its ok if you know the array dimension is 50 * 50, yet if you have array like {m_1 +m_2 + ...+ m_50} and you know that total number of m_1 + m_2 + m_3 ... + m_50 = 1000, how would you alloc it?

Comment: @Jaky Sorry but i can't understand. `m_1 + m_2 + m_3 ... + m_50 = 1000` how? what is `m`?

Comment: m_1,m_2.. can vary this is the main problem